# Proof that if $\lim s_n=0$ then $\lim\sqrt{s_n}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

Here's the question: Suppose $(s_n)$ is a sequence of non-negative real numbers, and $\lim( s_n) = 0$. Prove that $\lim(\sqrt{s_n})=0$.

Here's my proof. Can someone please verify it or offer suggestions for improvement?

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $(s_n)$ is convergent, we can find an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n > N$, $|s_n| < {\epsilon}^2$

Since $s_n > 0$, $|s_n| = s_n$

Therefore, $s_n < {\epsilon}^2$. Taking square roots on both sides, we get $\sqrt{s_n} < \epsilon$. That is, $|\sqrt{s_n} - 0| < \epsilon$.

This completes the proof.

Comment: The proof is good. I may be more specific in saying that $(s_n)$ converges to zero, instead of just being a convergent sequence.

Comment: Note that $|s_n|<\epsilon^2$ implies $s_n<\epsilon^2$ even if we do not assume $s_n>0$. Maybe you wanted to say something else?

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect proof. You use the definitions in the right way and produce nice $\varepsilon$ in the end. Congratulations!